# AS2 check whether string is changed or function is triggered

Tags: flash, function, callback, actionscript-2, listener

I have question on which I can't find any answear.

Example:

In _root exists function "**path=load_Path()**" which is triggered when an button is pressed. The result of this function can be "*photos/folder1/image.jpg*" or "*folder1/textpage/*" or any other path.
What I'm trying to find out is how to get value of "**path**" automatically when it's changed or get callback whenever function "**load_Path()**" is triggered.

I don't have possibility to access this function because it's in _root SWF which I can't edit.

Thanks for any reply.

Regards, Artur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the 'watch' method is what you need.

It's method signature is:

public watch(name: String, callback: Function, [userData: Object]) : Boolean

It will let you define a property to watch and a callback function that gets triggered when the property changes.

Was this helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it... Btw - Can I use `watch()` for checking array objects changes? I mean `image.name[currentImg-1] image.watch("name", myCallbackFunction);` I've tried this but I couldn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot edit root SWF, you will not be able to get callback when the function is triggered. I would advice checking the value constantly (per frame or per second), something like that:

```
function checkPath() {
  trace(_root.path);
}
onEnterFrame = checkPath; //check every frame
//OR
setTimeout(checkPath, 1000); //check every second
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course I know that I can use intervals or `onEnterFrame` in this case, but it's not efficient coding way...

Comment: Yet there is no other way if callback functionality is not added to root swf at compile time.